# C++ Builder 12.0 does NOT show Android, iOS or MacOS target platforms

Tags: delphi, c++builder, rad-studio, c++builder-12-athens

This is an IDE question.

When I select a `New -> Multi-Device Application` project for C++Builder, only Windows 32-bit and Windows 64-bit compilation options for target platforms are available.

[image: C++ Builder available platforms]

However, when I select a `New -> Multi-Device Application` project for Delphi, all other compilation options for target platforms are available, like Android 32/64-bit, iOS (Device and Sim), and MacOS (ARM, 64)

[image: Delphi available platforms]

During installation, I chose all available target platforms also at the beginning.

(Before installing RAD Studio 12.0, RAD Studio 11.3 was installed on my computer, and I first uninstalled 11.3 and then installed the newer 12.0 version)

"Add Platform" popup is also grayed out.

[image]

The operating system is Windows 11.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

I tried uninstalling the whole IDE and reinstalled it again 3 times, but the problem persists.

I also deleted all the contents of the Embarcadero folder in `C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero` while restarting the installs again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As written in "[What's New](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/What%27s_New#Removed_iOS_and_Android)" document, support for iOS and Android platform has been removed in C++ Builder 12 Athens.

> RAD Studio Athens removed the iOS 64-bit and Android 32-bit platforms
> because it cannot support the platforms if it does not support the
> deployment of apps to their Stores. Please use 11.3 to build for iOS
> or Android with C++.

From the [Supported Target Platforms](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Supported_Target_Platforms) document it is visible that C++ Builder 12 Athens supports only Windows platforms.

You cannot do anything to fix that. You can use older C++ Builder 11.3 to continue using platforms that were removed.

---

C++ Builder compilers are going through a major upgrade and this work had a priority over supporting Android and iOS at this time. This work is also a foundation for potential future support for other platforms, including ones that are now removed. See: [Clang Upgrade](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/What%27s_New#Clang_Upgrade)

Comment: This is the right answer but it is wrong.
Like many others, I have been using C++Builder for a long time and I pay for mobile support.
I also pay for updates that are supposed to be improvements: more features and less bugs, not features removal.
So what I have to do? I have to go on paying for updates and support but using an old version hoping that maybe one day there will be a "potential future support for other platforms"?
Am I the only one to consider this behavior of Embarcadero incorrect and illegal?

Comment: @steve.b Yes, it is wrong to to mislead the customers. That C++ Builder had issues with mobile support was visible since Android never got 64-bit compiler required for deploying to the Play Store. But I am afraid you will have to tell your complaints directly to the Embarcadero as they are the only ones in position to invest more and speed up their development process.

Comment: I apologize, I know this is not the place for my complaints.
I wrote to Embarcadero and also directly to David Millington, I'm waiting for answers...

Comment: @steve.b No worries. I fully understand your pain, although I am not a C++ Builder user myself.